# Build an e-commerce database using Prisma

Tags: database, mongodb, prisma

I'm working on a personal e-commerce project. I encounter some difficulties regarding the understanding of the collections and their relationships. The e-commerce is meant to sell digital products. So I don't have to worry about inventory management and delivery address.

To create my MongoDB database, I use the Prisma ORM.

```js
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  firstname String
  lastname String
  email String @unique
  password String

  cart Cart? // [User] one-to-one [Cart]
  orders Order[] // [User] one-to-many [Order]
  sessions  Session[] // [User] one-to-many [Session]

  @@map("users")
}

model Session {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  active Boolean @default(true)
  userAgent String?

  userId String @db.ObjectId
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("sessions")
}

model ResetPasswordToken {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  expiresAt DateTime

  token String @unique
  userId String @db.ObjectId
  isValid Boolean @default(true)

  @@map("reset_password_tokens")
}

model Cart {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  cartItems CartItem[] // [Cart] one-to-many [CartItem]

  userId String @unique @db.ObjectId
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("carts")
}

model CartItem {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  productId String @db.ObjectId
  quantity Int

  cartId String @db.ObjectId
  cart Cart @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("cart_items")
}

model Order {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  status Status
  totalPrice Float

  orderItems OrderItem[] // [Order] one-to-many [OrderItem]

  userId String @db.ObjectId
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("orders")
}

enum Status {
  PENDING
  CANCELED
  COMPLETED
}

model OrderItem {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  productId String @db.ObjectId
  quantity Int

  orderId String @db.ObjectId
  order Order @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("order_items")
}

model Product {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  name String
  url String
  description String
  price Float

  @@map("products")
}
```

Here are my Prisma models.

As it's non permanent, I'm not sure if I should declare an explicit relation between CartItem/OrderItem and Product.

Feel free to tell me if you have any recommendations, improvements to suggest to me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As `CartItem` and `OrderItem` refer to a specific product, it would make sense to have an explicit relation to the `Product` model. This will allow you to easily fetch product details when querying cart or order items. You can optionally add the below relation:

```
model CartItem {
  // ...
  product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  // ...
}

model OrderItem {
  // ...
  product Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  // ...
}
```

Apart from that your models looks good.